# How can I stop the loop after max wrong answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

This is an exercise from Introduction to CompSci and Programming in Python from OCW MIT. I modified it a little bit. The problem is I want to stop the program when I reached the max wrong answer but it stops if I try two times. Why two times ? How can I fix this ? As a new starter should I ask every question here ? Thanks to all

```
n = 0
max_guesses = 3
n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :)\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")

if n == "left" or "Left":
    print("You're out of lost forest")
while n == "right" or n == "Right":
    n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n******       ***\n  :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
    n =+ 1
    for n in range (max_guesses):
        break
print("Game over! You ran out of your lives")
```

Comment: [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Break works but as I said it gives me only two lives even if I change max_guesses to 5 it still stops after 2 try

Comment: why is `n=0` and then a string? why set `n` to +1 and overwrite the input? did you mean ` n  += 1` (incease n by 1? you cant do that with a string) for loop does not make sense - use `if n >live_count: break` - then print the isdead-message

Comment: I think you didn't understand what `range` does and what the `in` operator does. If you want to check whether `n` is equal to `max_guesses`, just use `n == max_guesses`.

Comment: I realized that there's a problem about string and int but it still gives me two lives. Why is that ?

Comment: I know I don't understand concepts properly but here I wonder why this code gives me two lives

Comment: *As a new starter should I ask every question here ?* No, you should research the problem thoroughly first. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors that contribute to your code not working properly

- Your variable n is the same as the value you get from the value you input best to separate those into different values to make it easier to avoid hard to detect errors
- You need to have a condition that checks if n >= max_guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community, we try to discuss the issues here rather than looking for a whole solution.

I suggest you to first learn the very basics of programming like the decision making, control flows (i.e if statements and loops).
Also, try to attempt the question, multiple numbers of times with different logics and inputs at runtime. it will give you a better understanding of logical analysis.

Here's one of the ways you could have added the logic.

```
#Maximum allowed guesses
max_guesses = 3

def func1():
    
    #Input string 'left' or 'right'
    in_str = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :)\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
    
    #Number of attempts made
    n = 1
    
    if in_str.lower() == "left":
        print("You're out of lost forest")
    
    while in_str.lower() == "right":
        in_str = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n******       ***\n  :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
        n += 1
        if in_str.lower() == "left":
            print("You're out of lost forest")
            break
        if n >= max_guesses:
            print("Game over!!!")
            break
    
    print("Total attempts made by user: ",n)
    
func1()
```

Answer (score -1):

I have attempted to fix your code however, I have had to remove the for loop and change the variable names. Hopefully, it helps.

```
n = 1
max_guesses = 3
a = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :)\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")

if a.lower() == "left":
    print("You're out of lost forest")
while a.lower() == "right":
    if n == 3:
        print("Game over! You ran out of your lives")
        break
    else:
        a = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n******       ***\n  :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
        n += 1
```